# How can I grab a value of a column that is set as a string?

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a table that contains a column with a list of levels. This column has a data type of string. I am trying to grab the value of the level as an integer to give me the list of of people that have a level under a certain number.

I tried running this:

```
    SELECT ukey, game_progress
    FROM point_review.vw_ft_level_progress a
    INNER JOIN point_review.vw_dim_level_progress b on a.game_progress_key = b.game_progress_key
    where ukey = 2111222 AND game_progression_type = 'Level' 
    and (CAST(REGEXP_REPLACE(game_progress, 'LEVEL ', '') as INTEGER)) < 15
```

However, I keep getting an error that says: The format or data contains a bad character.

This is in Teradata

TABLE A

| Column 1 | Column 2 |
| --- | --- |
| Joey | Level 2 |
| Rachel | Level 4 |
| Ross | Level 30 |
| Pheobe | Level 2 |
| Monica | Level 3 |
| Chandler | Level 20 |

RESULT should be only: Joey, Rachel, Phoebe and Monica since these have less than Level 15.

////

| Column 1 | Column 2 |
| --- | --- |
| Joey | Level 2 |
| Rachel | Level 4 |
| Pheobe | Level 2 |
| Monica | Level 3 |

Comment: which db you are really using

Comment: Repeating my comment from one to an answer. If this DB is of your own design, why store the level as a string? Store it as a number and voila! And if you need to show"Level x" somewhere just build that string when you need it.

Answer (score 1):

RegExes are case sensitive by default, switch to `REGEXP_REPLACE(game_progress, 'LEVEL ', '', 1, 1, 'i')` make it case insensitive.

If it's still failing you got other non-numeric data. Use this to find it:

```
SELECT DISTINCT game_progress
FROM point_review.vw_ft_level_progress a
where TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_REPLACE(game_progress, 'LEVEL ', '', 1, 1, 'i')) IS NULL
```

`TO_NUMBER` returns NULL for bad data instead of failing.

Answer (score 0):

could be you have some hidden spaces and or  case sensitive issue

```
SELECT ukey, game_progress
FROM point_review.vw_ft_level_progress a
INNER JOIN point_review.vw_dim_level_progress b on a.game_progress_key = b.game_progress_key
where ukey = 2111222 AND game_progression_type = 'Level' 
and (CAST(REGEXP_REPLACE(loweer(TRIM(game_progress)), 'level', '') as INTEGER)) < 15
```

Comment: Hi there, this did not work either :( anything else you think I can try?

Comment: based  on the sample you provided  this should work ..  be sure that the others condition are also true  ,,

Comment: @Charlie: Please specify concretely __what "did not work either"__. We can't help if we don't know the resulting output :(

Answer (score 0):

First. Thank you for posting your question here. I didn't have the need to use CAST before, but it's a very useful operator.

The solution might be much simpler than you think. Change all-uppercase 'LEVEL ' to 'Level ' and give it a try.

There are other alternatives that you may want to try:

1. Replace CAST with CAST(TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_REPLACE(game_progress, 'Level ', '')) AS INTEGER)
2. Use SPLIT_PART(string, delimiter, position) instead of REGEXP_REPLACE, like this
   CAST(SPLIT_PART(game_progress, ' ', 2) AS INTEGER)

This is what I tried using PostgreSQL:
[image]

Of course, your query is much more complex, but the idea is there. See what happens when I try with all-uppercase 'LEVEL '.
[image]

Sometimes error messages are misleading and that's why you had a hard time finding what was wrong with your query.

**IMPORTANT**:
My other suggestion is that you should restructure your columns. The 'Level' column, for example have 'Level ' defined on every line. You could simply have a column named 'Level'
that accepts integers, and then insert/update with integers. Then, all your queries can work without the need of complex operators.

I hope that this was helpful.

Have a great day!

Comment: I think the IMPORTANT bit is th emost important bit of the answer. Why store a game level as a string if it's really an integer. If you have to display it as "Level xx" then just build that string when you need it.

Comment: @PaulPalmpje Use-case driven upfront-design of column-type and decoupling from output-formatting would definitely avoid such troubles. But sometimes the DB-users (here asking) do not have permissions to do so (e.g. third-party managed or read-only DB). Please __put your comment to the question__, it may be the solution.