# Why is my query not working when I add additional filter?

Tags: sql

I have really tried to do everything to get this query to work but I am having no luck! Please see both queries below. The first one is working perfectly.

WORKS:

```
    select user_key, CAST(REGEXP_REPLACE(game_progres, 'LEVEL ', '') as INTEGER) 
    from database1.vw_ft_Game_rockroll a
    inner join database1vw_dim_Game_rockroll b on a.game_key = b.game_key
    where user_key = 211111111 and game_type = 'LEVEL'
```

DOES NOT WORK:

```
    select user_key, CAST(REGEXP_REPLACE(game_progres, 'LEVEL ', '') as INTEGER) 
    from database1.vw_ft_Game_rockroll a
    inner join database1.vw_dim_Game_rockroll b on a.game_key = b.game_key
    where user_key = 211111111 and game_type = 'LEVEL' and CAST(REGEXP_REPLACE(game_progres, 'LEVEL ', '') as INTEGER) < 15
```

The only difference between these two queries is the additional filter of `and CAST(REGEXP_REPLACE(game_progression, 'LEVEL ', '') as INTEGER) < 15`. The error is: The format or data contains a bad character.

But I run the first query, and I don't see a bad format or bad character? Please let me know if I am missing anything!! Much appreciated!

Background: game_progres is a column that contains a string value: Level 1, Level 2, level 10, level 15 -- I want to filter on the number only and get the levels that are under 15.

Comment: They have the same view actually, made an edit. Both queries are exactly the same except the additional filter

Comment: There are probably additional spaces or non-printing characters in the column. Try running the replace without the cast and see if the lengths of the calculated fields match what you would expect i.e. a value of '1' has a length of 1, '11' length 2, '111' length 3 etc.

Comment: @Charlie You asked the [same question already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66356104/sql-error-2620-hy000-the-format-or-data-contains-a-bad-character): 
Fastest way to a good answer is improving [your original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66352258/how-can-i-grab-a-value-of-a-column-that-is-set-as-a-string), instead of repeating it. Please __consult help-pages on [ask]__!

Comment: Why would you store the progress level as a string in the first place? Store it as integer and your query will be a lot simpler. And if you have to display it... then build the string you want.